# Is there a way to reuse a terraform script and make changes to it?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm new to this terraform world and I've been assigned into the task of creating many configurations to azure with it.

I'm developing a `main.tf` script (which creates some resources, like resource group, vnets, kubernetes cluster, app services, etc.) and while coding it and executing
`Terraform apply`, it seems to only apply what changed doing in fact updates.

Then we deleted the resource group the script created and a colegue of mine had to run the same script with terraform creating a resource group with another name since i didn't had a required permission, after that, if i run the command `Terraform apply` it fails and gives errors, that say that the resource cannot be created because it already exists.

After reading some documentation i found that it might be because of the state
https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/index.html

Is the update of a script something that only works for each session of terraform?

Even doing a `Terraform refresh` doesn't seem to work.
Or probably I'm just mistaking and there is no way to update some resources.

EDIT: for some reason the state file that was on the storage only had a few things, the solution was to delete everything and create again.

Comment: Are you trying to make changes to existing resources?

Comment: Did you make manual changes to the resources you deployed with terraform? You said, "we deleted the resource group the script created." Did you delete it using `terraform destroy` or using the portal/CLI/etc? Also, could you please provide the exact error message you received?

Comment: @YannStoneman The resource with everything inside was delete in Azure, but then we create another resource group with a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the new resources, there is nothing more, the Terraform script helps you create the resources you set in the script.

For the existing resources, when you make changes in the script that you already deployed via the Terraform, then it will check the state file to make sure what changes the resources should update. If there is no state file ( or you delete it), then it will deploy the Terraform script directly, but if any resources you want to deploy already exists, then it will fail due to the existing resources. And the command `terraform refresh` just updates the last state of the resources in the Terraform script that you already deployed. If the deployment failed and the state file has no resources in it, then `refresh` is not useful.

Comment: Then that means that if someone else deploys the script and then I try to deploy the same script with some changes, since i don't have the initial state, there is no way for me to do the update?

Comment: @Nmaster88 You can import all the resources in the Terraform script into a state file. Then you can update them.

Comment: That makes sense I've now found some articles talking about remote state for a team environment.

Comment: @Nmaster88 Well, if it's helpful to you please accept it.

Comment: ok. Checking the file of the state it only had a few things, that was the problem and i don't know why that happened.

Comment: @Nmaster88 It depends on your Terraform script. When the script deploys, all the resources' state will be written down to the state file.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else ran `terraform apply` for you because you didn't have access, and now you want to modify that terraform and run it yourself, you need to get the state file that was generated when that other person ran it. You absolutely have to maintain the Terraform state file somewhere, so that it can be accessed on subsequent runs. You should really configure a [Terraform backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/index.html), instead of using local state files.

You need to be aware that Terraform stores everything it does in the state file, and refers to that file before every run. A `terraform refresh` only tells Terraform to refresh the state of the things that are in the state file, it doesn't rebuild the state file from scratch. Understanding Terraform state files is so fundamental to the use of Terraform that you really need to understand this before using it.